# Changing the color ramp in arcgis javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geotiff-tiff, color-ramp

Using the arcgis javascript api, I am displaying geotiffs. What I want to do is change the color ramp in these images. I've looked through the api and I have not seen anything. Does anyone know where I can get some examples of this?

Comment: How are you displaying these GeoTIFFs? Are you connecting to an Image Service or are you somehow displaying them completely client-side using MapImageLayer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow clients to change layer appearance and behavior in your map service, you can enable dynamic layers after you've already published a map service. Dynamic layers can increase the amount of interaction that users are able to have with your maps.